# Can't delete row from single column table

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have problem with the query to delete a row from table(I am using MySQL lite), I'm using data bound comobox to select what to delete but I get this error {"Invalid column name 'Football'."} on executing the command

```
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Sports WHERE Sport = " + cbSelectSport.Text + "", con);
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to create the query, use a parameterized query and pass the criteria as a parameter

Comment: You are inviting [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work).

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? The tag says MySQL but the code is SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify textvalue in single quotation marks ''.

```
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Sports WHERE Sport = '" + cbSelectSport.Text + "'", con);
```

Comment: Better yet, use a parameterized query to avoid this problem entirely *and* improve performance

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with you syntax.

I don't know the type of the sport column, but I think need to enclose your value in **quotes**( *single or double*).

```
new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Sports WHERE Sport = \"" + cbSelectSport.Text + "\", con);
```

*or*

```
new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Sports WHERE Sport = '" + cbSelectSport.Text + "', con);
```

Comment: It's mysql if I trust the tag

Comment: Better yet, use a parameterized query to avoid this problem entirely *and* improve performance

Comment: This isn't a real solution - image what will happen if the user enters a `'` or `"`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree with you. But I don't know C# and how to use the parameterized query.

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation should be avoided in almost every case. You should use parameterized queries whenever possible. You avoid conversions, SQL injection attacks and the code is typically faster because the server can reuse execution plans

Writing a parameterized query is also easier:

```
using(var con=new SqlConnection(...))
{
    con.Open();
    var cm = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Sports WHERE Sport = @sports", con);
    var parameter=cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sports",cbSelectSport.Text);
    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
 };
```

This way the parameter values are passed out of band (ie outside the query) without converting to text. This is extremely useful when you want to pass decimal or date values.

Most people would warn against using `AddWithValue` because it makes too many assumptions based on its input value that can hurt performance. In this case you can use `Add` to create the parameter, then set its value, size, precision etc:

```
    var parameter=cm.Parameters.Add("@sports",SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    parameter.Size=20;
    parameter.Value=cbSelectSport.Text;
```

Comment: I agree 99.99999%. However your comment about reusing plans is a common myth. Ad hoc queries have their execution plan cached just like everything else and can be reused.

Comment: Not a myth - with a parameterized query the server can create a plan that can match any value passed to the parameter. With an ad-hoc query plan the server will have to guess which parts are actually parameters in order to pick a previous plan. If that fails, a new one will be created

Comment: It caches the plan just the same. It is not always as effective though.

Comment: Here is an excellent post about this topic. It isn't the cut and dry "parameterized queries are faster" that many people claim. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/scarydba/2009/10/05/ad-hoc-queries-don_1920_t-reuse-execution-plans_3A00_-myth-or-fact/

Comment: @SeanLange I don't think the article says what you think it says. It compares ad-hoc, parameterized queries and stored procedures and states that with ad-hoc ` ... you’re going to get a different execution plan. That’s because the full text of the query is used to determine if the existing plan will work for the new query ...`. It's the parameterized version that reuses execution plans. SQL Server can use parameter sniffing to parameterize even in ad-hoc queries but that doesn't always work

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add the single quote:

`SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Sports WHERE Sport = '" + cbSelectSport.Text + "'", con);`

Answer (score 0):

You should use parametrized query to prevent SQL Injection attack. Also it will solve your problem. By the way you can just add single quotes to your query.

`"DELETE FROM Sports WHERE Sport = '" + cbSelectSport.Text + "'"`

Comment: This won't work if the combo contains a single quote. Which is why the OP should use parameterized queries